# Oberbegriff für »Erstellen« und »Verändern«

Tags: single-word-request, synonym

Ich suche einen Oberbegriff für die Verben *Erstellen* und *Verändern.* Es geht darum einen Arbeitsschritt mit einem Wort zu beschreiben. Der Arbeitsschritt enthält das Erstellen, wenn etwas nicht vorhanden ist und das Verändern, wenn es bereits vorhanden ist.

Einige Ideen:

*Aktualisieren* trifft nicht ganz zu, weil es eher das Verändern beschreibt.

*Bilden* trifft ebenfalls nicht zu, da es eher das Erstellen beschreibt.

Es handelt sich um eine Geschäftslogik die durch ein Programm automatisiert erzeugt werden soll.

Ein Beispielsatz könnte also lauten:

> Die Geschäftslogik erstellen/verändern.

Comment: „Zum Schreiben öffnen“ trifft – bei Dateien – beide Sachverhalte, aber ist eben mehr als ein Wort und auch nicht z.B. für Pflaumenkuchen anwendbar. Und den kann man ja auch erstellen und verändern.

Comment: Falls Du Neuschöpfungen akzeptierst: "kreifizieren".

Comment: Neuschöpfungen gehen leider nicht, da es sich um eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit handelt und ich dort nicht noch sprachliche Neuerungen einführen möchte. "Zum Schreiben öffnen" setzt auch ein Vorhandensein der Datei voraus.

Comment: Jetzt mit genauerem Beispielsatz.

Comment: Und morgen suchen wir einen Oberbegriff für gelb und blau, weil Heiner eine gelbe oder blaue Hose kaufen will. ;) Leg die Scheu vor dem Wort *oder* ab und fertig.

Comment: @userunknown: "Farbe".

Comment: Eine farbige Hose. Nailed it!

Comment: Eine Geschäftslogik kann man nicht erstellen. Der Begriff Geschäftslogik ist ein Fachbegriff der Softwarearchitektur und wird nur von Softwarearchitekten und damit verwandten Berufen verwendet. Die Geschäftslogik ist die Summe aller Prozesse (use cases), die mit einem Computerprogramm durchgeführt werden sollen. Aus Sicht des SW-Architekten ist die Geschäftslogik daher vom Kunden vorgegeben, also nichts was man selbst erstellt. Aus Sicht des Kunden ist diese Logik ebenfalls vorgegeben, sie entspricht den Tätigkeiten, die man auch ohne Programm schon immer getan hat.

Comment: (Forts.) Was man erstellen kann ist eine *Beschreibung* der Geschäftslogik, nicht die Logik selbst.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Der Oberbegriff von gelb und blau im Sinn der gestellten Frage ist nicht farbig, denn zu farbig gehören auch grün, rot, orange usw. Soweit ich landunter verstanden habe, sucht er einen Oberbegriff nur für die beiden Wörter *erstellen* und *verändern*, aber für keine weiteren Tätigkeiten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Richtig - meine Antwort war bewusst so gewählt, dass sie hervorhebt, dass "gelb" und "blau" eine willkürliche Teilmenge aller Farben sind, während mir zu den vom Autor gewählten Begriffen, die die unterschiedlichen Arten von "Schreibzugriffen" beschreiben, keine weiteren auf derselben Ebene einfallen würden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "Was man erstellen kann ist eine *Beschreibung* der Geschäftslogik, nicht die Logik selbst." - ist das nicht zu kurz gegriffen? Dann müsste man ja auch sagen, dass man keinen Text erstellen kann, nur eine Repräsentation davon. Falls die besagte "Beschreibung der Geschäftslogik" selber ausführbar ist, dann beschreibt diese Beschreibung eben nicht nur, sondern sie "ist" gewissermaßen die Geschäftslogik. Zumindest in einer Software, deren Zweck in der Erzeugung von Geschäftslogiken liegt, wird man sich sicherlich nicht mit Wortungetümen wie "Beschreibung einer ...

Comment: ... Geschäftslogik" herumschlagen müssen; üblicherweise werden dann die Dokumente/Projekte/sonstigen Verwaltungseinheiten in Bezug auf das Programm selber als "Geschäftslogik" bezeichnet.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Kürzen, löschen, komprimieren, verschlüsseln?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Englische erlaubt hier die schöne Abkürzung

> CRUD

(für "create", "retrieve", "update" und "delete")

und lässt einfach die Buchstaben der Operationen weg, die grade nicht zutreffen. Da wir uns anscheinend in IT-Fachsprache befinden und nicht im Deutschunterricht, darfst du m.A. nach durchaus solche Begrifflichkeit verwenden.

Deine Operation "Erstellen und/oder Verändern" ist also eine

> CU-Operation

Falls du wirklich unbedingt "natürliche Sprache" brauchst, würde ich tatsächlich "Erstellen/Verändern" schreiben und einzeln aufführen. Hier ginge mir Klarheit vor Schönheit.

Comment: Obwohl ich Informatiker bin und mit die Abkürzung CRUD absolut geläufig ist, würde ich bei einer "CU-Operation" zuallererst an einen "Abschied" denken ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es ist u.U. hilfreich, den Begriff zumindestens einmal zu erklären. Danach hätte ich aber keinerlei Probleme, ihn auch zu verwenden...

Comment: Das macht im Rahmen der Arbeit am meisten Sinn

Answer (score 1):

Schau in das Menü irgend einer Software, das die Unterpunkte »Verändern«, »Erstellen« (oder auch »Löschen« und ähnliche) enthält. Der Oberpunkt dieser Unterpunkte heißt so gut wie immer:

### Bearbeiten

Und das ist auch genau dein gesuchter Oberbegriff. Und genau in diesem Sinn wird »Bearbeiten« schon seit mehr als 20 Jahren in der IT (damals noch EDV) verwendet. Das ist ein längst eingebürgerter Begriff, daher sollte man gerade in Software-Menüs dafür auch keinen anderen Begriff als Oberbegriff verwenden (außer man legt es absichtlich darauf an, die Anwender zu irritieren).

Ergänzung:
Falls es wirklich um ein Software-Menü geht: Der Hauptpunkt »Bearbeiten« sollte der zweite oder dritte Menüpunkt sein. Befasse dich mit Usability und Software-Ergonomie um zu lernen, was Standards für Menüs sind. Erfinde das Rad nicht neu, sonder kopiere die Menüs ähnlicher weit verbreiteter Programme. Das erhöht die Akzeptanz deines eigenen Programms.

Comment: Es geht leider nicht um ein Softwaremenü, deshalb ist auch das Wort Bearbeiten nicht sinnvoll. Es geht einfach nur um das Schreiben einer Anforderung. Dabei sollte der abstrakte Oberbegriff auf die zwei Arbeitsschritte heruntergebrochen werden.

Comment: Dann stelle in deiner Frage bitte mehr Kontext bereit. Erzähle, worum es geht, dann bekommst du treffsicherere Antworten und zwingst die Leute, die dir helfen wollen, nicht dazu, Rätsel raten zu müssen.

Comment: Ich habe explizit nach einem Oberbegriff für Erstellen/Verändern gefragt und das ist nicht Bearbeiten, denn ich kann nicht etwas bearbeiten, das noch nicht erstellt wurde. Der Bezug zur Datei war nur ein Beispielsatz.

Comment: Unter Bearbeiten finde ich immer "Kopieren, Ausschneiden, Einfügen", dagegen "Speichern (unter)" und "Neu" unter "Datei".

Answer (score 0):

Bei `bereitstellen` oder `sicherstellen` ist es egal, ob etwas schon existiert oder nicht. Je nach Formulierungskontext ginge auch `forcieren`, bzw. `erzwingen`. Wenn Du nach einer Überschrift suchst, dann wirst Du um ein weiteres Wort für den Kontext kaum herumkommen ohne die Aussagekraft leiden zu lassen (z.B. `Datensatz sicherstellen` versus `Bereitstellung`).

Answer (score -1):

**Formular**

Ich hatte eine ähnliche Situation mit einer ähnlichen Fragestellung und in meinem Kontext hat das Wort "Formular" Sinn gemacht. Das ist zwar linguistisch gesehen nicht der Oberbegriff, aber es könnte evtl. trotzdem hilfreich sein.